# HIbernate - HBM.xml Automatic generation from DB Schema

Tags: hibernate

Is there any plugin available for Eclipse or Netbeans or any other IDE which can help me generate the hbm.xml by directly reading the schema from the database.

Writing those XMLs seem to be unnecessary waste of time, and feel it should be automated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For NetBeans, have a look at [Using Hibernate in a Web Application](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/hibernate-webapp.html).

For Eclipse, use the [Hibernate Tools](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/tools.html) plugin. Here is [a tutorial](http://iablog.sybase.com/paulley/2009/02/reverse-engineering-sql-anywhere-with-hibernate-tools-part-trois/) demonstrating how to use its **Reverse Engineering** feature.

Answer (score 1):

[Hibernate Synchronizer](http://hibernatesynch.sourceforge.net/) can help also.

Answer (score 0):

[Hibernate Tools](https://www.hibernate.org/255.html) includes all sorts of tools for doing hbm and class conversions.

Comment: could you please give specific pointers. I am looking for a tool to generate the hbm xml by reading the table schema directly. 

i am not interested in writing the whole set of xmls.